# Fast suffix generation in Python

Tags: python

I have a string s and I need to generate set of suffixes from the string. For example, `abcdef` will lead to array `[f, ef, def, cdef, bcdef, abcdef]`. I'm doing this in straightforward way:

```
def get_suffixes(s):
    sb_set = set()
    sb = ''
    for i in range(len(s)-1,-1,-1):
        sb = s[i] + sb
        sb_set.add(sb)
```

Is there more optimal/fast way to do so? I need to generate huge amount of such suffixes (string s is 10K long)

Comment: Why not use a `buffer` or `memoryview` instead of taking all the slices?

Comment: What will you do with the resultant set?

Answer (score 3):

How about `set(s[a:] for a in xrange(len(s)))`?

(Not sure why you're using a set since the suffixes must be distinct, but I'm maintaining the use of set here since you said that's what you want.  You could also just use a list comprehension if you just want a list.)

Comment: Set comprehensions exist in recent versions of Python (2.7+): ``{s[a:] for a in range(len(s))}``. It's also worth noting sets don't preserve order.

Comment: why would you use a set?  since they are all different lengths arent they automagically distinct?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: That's true, but I'm just using set because the OP said that's what he wants.  He may want to intersect it with something else later, for example.

Comment: You may also use `xrange()` instead of `range()` and use a precalculated `len_s`=`len(s)` to speed up a little tiny bit.

Comment: @poplitea ``xrange()`` under the presumption that you are using 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

just use a list comprehension .. convert to a set later when you need set operations

```
s = "abcdef"    
suffixes = [s[i:] for i in range(1,len(s))]
```

see

```
>>> s = "abcdef"
>>> suffixes = [s[i:] for i in range(1,len(s))]
>>> suffixes
['bcdef', 'cdef', 'def', 'ef', 'f']
```

or

```
>>> s = "abcdef"
>>> suffixes = [s[i:] for i in range(len(s))]
>>> suffixes
['abcdef','bcdef', 'cdef', 'def', 'ef', 'f']
```